# Using input function with remote files in snakemake

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-storage, snakemake

I want to use a function to read inputs file paths from a dataframe and send them to my snakemake rule. I also have a helper function to select the remote from which to pull the files.

```py
from snakemake.remote.GS import RemoteProvider as GSRemoteProvider
from snakemake.remote.SFTP import RemoteProvider as SFTPRemoteProvider
from os.path import join
import pandas as pd

configfile: "config.yaml"
units = pd.read_csv(config["units"]).set_index(["library", "unit"], drop=False)
TMP= join('data', 'tmp')


def access_remote(local_path):
    """ Connnects to remote as defined in config file"""
    provider = config['provider']
    if provider == 'GS':
        GS = GSRemoteProvider()
        remote_path = GS.remote(join("gs://" + config['bucket'], local_path))
    elif provider == 'SFTP':
        SFTP = SFTPRemoteProvider(
            username=config['user'],
            private_key=config['ssh_key']
        )
        remote_path = SFTP.remote(
            config['host'] + ":22" + join(base_path, local_path)
        )
    else: 
        remote_path = local_path
    return remote_path


def get_fastqs(wc):
    """
    Get fastq files (units) of a particular library - sample 
    combination from the unit sheet.
    """
    fqs = units.loc[
        (units.library == wc.library) & 
        (units.libtype == wc.libtype), 
        "fq1"
    ]
    return {
      "r1": list(map(access_remote, fqs.fq1.values)),
    }

# Combine all fastq files from the same sample / library type combination
rule combine_units:
  input: unpack(get_fastqs)
  output:
    r1 = join(TMP, "reads", "{library}_{libtype}.end1.fq.gz")
  threads: 12
  run:
    shell("cat {i1} > {o1}".format(i1=input['r1'], o1=output['r1']))
```

My config file contains the bucket name and provider, which are passed to the function. This works as expected when running simply `snakemake`.

However, I would like to use the kubernetes integration, which requires passing the provider and bucket name in the command line. But when I run:

`snakemake -n --kubernetes --default-remote-provider GS --default-remote-prefix bucket-name`

I get this error:

```
ERROR :: MissingInputException in line 19 of Snakefile:
Missing input files for rule combine_units:
bucket-name/['bucket-name/lib1-unit1.end1.fastq.gz', 'bucket-name/lib1-unit2.end1.fastq.gz', 'bucket-name/lib1-unit3.end1.fastq.gz']
```

The bucket is applied twice (once mapped correctly to each element, and once before the whole list (which gets converted to a string). Did I miss something ? Is there a good way to work around this ?

Comment: Could you provide the debugging output by executing the `snakemake` command with the `--debug` flag?

Comment: I have the exact same output when using `--debug`, unfortunately